# Unable to set dropdown values for combobox using webdriver python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

There is a webpage on which I am trying to fill form using python selenium. However I am struck at a combo-dropdown box as below.

Here is the Webpage code:

```
<select class="in select2-hidden-accessible" name="scrip[]" id="scrip" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
<option value="ACC19NOV">ACC 28-NOV-19</option>
<option value="ACC19DEC">ACC 26-DEC-19</option>
<option value="ACC20JAN">ACC 30-JAN-20</option>
<option value="ADANIENT19NOV">ADANIENT 28-NOV-19</option>
<option value="ADANIENT19DEC">ADANIENT 26-DEC-19</option>
<option value="ADANIENT20JAN">ADANIENT 30-JAN-20</option>
.
.
.
<option value="SBIN26DEC">SBIN 26-DEC-19</option>
.
.
</select>
```

Python code using `Select`:

```
test = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('script'))
```

Here it gives error that:

> NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="script"]"}
>     (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.108)

If I Try to access the element using 'Xpath' then somehow only partial values are passed in `send_keys`. Code below:

```
test = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="scrip"]')
test.send_keys('SBIN 26-DEC-19')
```

Only '26-DEC-19' gets passed and not able to move further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need change `test = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('scrip'))`. Because your id="scrip".

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
selectOpt = select(driver.find_element_by_id('scrip'))
# select by visible text
selectOpt.select_by_visible_text('SBIN 26-DEC-19')
```

Or you can find the options by xpath and click by text like below

```
selectEle = driver.find_element_by_id('scrip')
selectEle.click()
options=selectEle.find_elements_by_tag_name('option')
for optionEle in options:
    if optionEle.text == 'SBIN 26-DEC-19':
        optionEle.click()
         break
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a Typo mistake in my code where the id was *scrip* and not *script* which i was trying. Once the same was corrected the code gave proper results. Thanks for pointing it out.